# .find('.foo').text() as array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html with multiple things classed .text. I the perform

```
console.log($(whatever).find('.foo').text());
```

The result is a textstring with all the contents in it. Can I save it to an array instead somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `map` method to get this done

```
var textArray = $(whatever).find('.foo').map(function() {
   return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

This will get you an array.. If you want to display it as a string then just use `join` along with it.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/9F3MD/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [];

$(whatever).find('.foo').each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).text());
});
```